# In MySQL my date format is (mm-dd-yyyy) so m not able to retreive the total sales of year 2020

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

- car_model: id, name, price
- country: id, name
- Sales: model_id, country_id, quantity, sales_date

All the country wise sale records of its cars in table sales, storing quantity sold on particular date

need to write a query calculates country-wise sales for all of the car models along with the total_sales generated for the year 2020 in ascending order

```
SELECT
    country.name, car_model.name,
    SUM(car_model.price * sales.quantity) AS total_sales
FROM sales
JOIN country ON country.id=sales.country_id
JOIN car_model ON car_model.id=sales.model_id
WHERE sales.sales_date between '01-01-2020' and '12-31-2020'
GROUP BY country.name,car_model.name
ORDER BY total_sales asc;
```

this is the code i tried but it gives the output for all the years and i just need the 2020 sales record

#This question is from Hackerrnk so i cant show the table structure

Comment: I mean you need change `WHERE sales.sales_date between '01-01-2020' and '31-12-2020'` to WHERE sales.sales_date between '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31 23:59:59'

Comment: Please provide your tables structure for better help

Comment: You should change your sales_date type to date. Never store dates in strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below solution.

```
WITH models
     AS (SELECT car_model.NAME
         FROM   car_model
                JOIN sales
                  ON ( sales.model_id = car_model.id )
         GROUP  BY 1)
SELECT country.NAME,
       models.NAME,
       Sum(sales.quantity * car_model.price)
FROM   country
       JOIN sales
         ON ( country.id = sales.country_id )
       JOIN car_model
         ON ( sales.model_id = car_model.id )
       JOIN models
         ON ( car_model.NAME = models.NAME )
WHERE  sales_date LIKE '%2020%'
GROUP  BY 1,
          2
ORDER  BY 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT c.name, m.name, SUM(m.price*s.quantity) AS total_sales
FROM sales s
INNER JOIN country c ON c.id=s.country_id
INNER JOIN car_model m ON m.id=s.model_id
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(s.sales_date, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY c.name, m.name ORDER BY c.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `sales_date` column uses CHAR(10) or VARCHAR() for a data type, and that the text string values look like `15-10-2020` for 15-Oct-2020.

If you use this (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
STR_TO_DATE(sales.sales_date,'%d-%c-%Y')
  BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-13-31'
```

You'll get useful results.

Better yet, reformat your sales_date column to use the DATE data type rather than some text string representation. MySQL offers a wealth of date and time processing features which you unlock by using the correct data types (or with kludgey function calls like my example above).

Comment: thanks for the response but didn't worked for me ,now am not getting the output at all

Answer (score 0):

WHERE sales.sales_date between '01-01-2020' and '31-12-2020'

is the same as

where substring_index(sales_date,'-',-1) = 2020

Comment: this code didnt worked for me its working same for me as it was

Answer (score 0):

Your sales_date format is in varchar datatype. you can check it using `desc sales;` query. Please find below the query to change varchar to date data type it will definitely help you.

```
select  *from sales where str_to_date(sales_date,'%m/%d/%Y') between '2020-01-01' and '2020-12-31';
```